# Converting from C++ string to unsigned char* and back

Tags: c++, string, casting, unsigned-char

What would be the code to convert an std::string to unsigned char* and back?

```
str = "1234567891234567"
unsigned char* unsignedStr = ConvertStrToUnsignedCharPointer(str);
str1 = ConvertUnsignedCharToStr(unsignedStr);
```

`str` and `str1` must be same with no loss of precision.

Comment: `unsigned char*` ? Are you sure `std::string` is the right tool for your job ?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `unsigned char const*`?

Comment: What do you want `unsigned char` for? Storing binary data? Maybe you actually want a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>`?

Answer (score 15):

```
auto str1 = std::string{"1234567891234567"}; // start with string
auto chrs = str.c_str(); // get constant char* from string
auto str2 = std::string{ chrs }; // make string from char*
```

Unsigned char*:

```
auto uchrs = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(chrs));
```

Using vectors instead of raw pointers:

```
using namespace std;

auto str1 = string{"1234567891234567"};
vector<char> chars{ begin(str1), end(str1) };

vector<unsigned char> uchars;
transform(begin(str1), end(str1), back_inserter(uchars),
    [](char c) { return reinterpret_cast<unsigned char>(c); });
```

Comment: Casting away the constness of `.c_str()` result is rather ungood.

Comment: I know; I was simply answering the question "What would be the code to convert an std::string to unsigned char*". My usual answer to this question is "use vectors".